# Why can not I use the O365 package in python?

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api, office365

Here is the code that I am using to interactive with Office 365:

```
from O365 import Account
credentials = ('...', '...')
account = Account(credentials)
if account.authenticate(scopes=['basic', 'message_all']):
   print('Authenticated!')
```

After I run the python file, I get a URL, and I click the URL:

AADSTS50194: Application '...'(test) is not configured as a multi-tenant application. Usage of the /common endpoint is not supported for such applications created after '10/15/2018'. Use a tenant-specific endpoint or configure the application to be multi-tenant.

I set "Accounts in this organizational directory only" because I only want the people in my company can access the app.

I also set this (as you can see, I have set the redirect URL ):
[image]

Am I missing something here?

Here is my new code:

```
from O365 import Account

credentials = ('..', '..')

# the default protocol will be Microsoft Graph

account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type='credentials', tenant_id='..')
if account.authenticate():
   print('Authenticated!')

storage = account.storage()
print(storage)
my_drive = storage.get_default_drive()  # or get_drive('drive-id')
print(my_drive)
root_folder = my_drive.get_root_folder()
attachments_folder = my_drive.get_special_folder('attachments')
```

It can get "Authenticated!", but I get the following error:

```
Client Error: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root | Error Message: Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.

{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"Access token is empty.","innerError":{"date":"2022-04-07T01:24:20","request-id":"be71cdcf-6f69-4d6f-b344-588d0b693253","client-request-id":"be71cdcf-6f69-4d6f-b344-588d0b693253"}}}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to find your tenant Id (it will be listed on the application registration)

[image]

and then pass that in eg

```html
from O365 import Account

credentials = ('my_client_id', 'my_client_secret')

# the default protocol will be Microsoft Graph

account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type='credentials', tenant_id='my-tenant-id')
if account.authenticate():
   print('Authenticated!')
```

Comment: Hi Glen, thanks for your reply, could you review my new error?

Comment: Looks like your missing the scopes in the request I didn't include them in the example I posted.